# Change all domains in links on a website

Tags: php, jquery

need some advice on how to fix an ugly situation. our forum has resided on a couple of different domains over the years. we lost one domain that was in use 5-6 yrs ago and apparently some posts on our forum still have links in the threads that point to the old domain. what would be the most efficient way to change all links that point to

`http://www.olddomain.com/stuff`

point to

```
http://www.newdomain.com/stuff
```

the only part that has changed is the domain name, all thread variables in the url remain the same. is this something that is best done client side with javascript/jquery or should it be handled on a server level with a PHP function (dont know where to begin here..)? some pseudocode that doesn't seem to do what I need it to on the client side...

```
$('a').each(function() {
   var domanin = 'newdomain';

   if(href.search('olddomain.com') != -1) {      
      $(this).attr('href', newdomain);
   }
});
```

thank you

Comment: If running on a Linux server with Apache, start by looking at the mod_rewrite module and .htaccess!

Comment: Couldn't you do a global search and replace? Look for olddomain and change to newdomain?

Comment: @adeneo as Justin brought up, I do not have access to the old domains or I would have just wrote a 301 rule.

Comment: Unless he still has control over the old domain I don't believe he would be able to redirect the requests.

Comment: @JoseVega its an install of vbulletin - which is very outdated...

Comment: @JustinLucas correct we no longer have access to old domain

Comment: This should be done by modifying the actual database where the posts are stored to one-time update the domains in the posts to the new domain.  This would obviously take a back-end script that can access the database, find the errant domains, change them and write them back to the database.  Any server-side scripting language could be used that has a good library for accessing your database (PHP, Python, Java, etc...).

Comment: @jfriend00 would have to be PHP as I know a little there and nothing of the others. I'll start looking. thanks.

Comment: FYI, you might consider just stripping off the domains to make the domains in question be domain relative (starting with a / with no actual domain in them).  Then, if you ever change your domain again, these will still work.

Comment: There is a replacement variable manager in vBulletin that could be used for this, or you can access your DB and run `UPDATE post SET pagetext = REPLACE(pagetext,"http://my.old_domain.com/index.php?showtopic=","http://www.newdomain.com/showthread.php?t=")` or something similar. Remember to backup your DB before trying anything.

Comment: @adeno thank you for reminding me about replacement variable manager. I can't mark a comment as the answer, but this is the answer! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think it will make more sense if you handle this in the back end. Search engines will not notice the change you make through JavaScript.

So I advise you search for those domains in your database and replace them there.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in JavaScript (w/ jQuery):

```
$('a').each(function() {
   var link = this.href;

   if(link.search('olddomain.com') != -1) {      
      this.href =  link.replace('olddomain.com', 'newdomain.com');
   }
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tHXxK/

However I would suggest changing the links in the database, just get rid of all the old references. To do this create a script that searches for the old URLs and replaces them, something like:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT [id], [link] FROM [table] WHERE [link] LIKE '%//olddomain.com/%' OR [link] LIKE '%//www.olddomain.com/%'", $db) or trigger_erroR(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_query($query)) {
    $iQuery = mysql_query("UPDATE [table] SET [link]='" . mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace(array('//olddomain.com/', '//www.olddomain.com/'), array('//newdomain.com/', '//www.newdomain.com/'), $row['link']) . "' WHERE [id]=" . $row['id']), $db) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: thanks I understand this is not best case but have no idea how to modify the database correctly and can't afford to go by trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Well you should probably do this on the server side, as it was said before, but if you can't for whatever reason, here is what you could do on the javascript side of things.

```
$('a').each(function() {
  this.host = 'www.newdomain.com';
});
```

Note that this example uses jQuery, but you could do the same in plain javascript with `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: thanks! I know its best to do it server side but to be honest, I have no idea how!

Answer (score 0):

If it'd be me, I would have used a server side script to replace all instances of the old domain with the new one and be done with it once and for all.
I assume your forum DB is rather a large one. For the sake of system resources you can write a multi-step script and do the job in multiple steps.
This is a better approach as it can improve the data consistency for search engines as well.

Comment: I understand that in theory but have absolutely no idea how to do it in practice. Would appreciate any info you feel like providing.